# Rename a column while keeping the previous column name

Tags: postgresql

When I'm renaming a column, there will be a hiccup between the previous version (which depends on the previous column name) and the newly deployed version (which depends on the new column name).

I wonder if there's a way for postgresql to rename a column and keeping the previous column name to work.

What I imagine might be some kind of a proxy column. I wonder if there is such a feature in Postgresql.

I understand that there is a way to solve this on the application layer. But if Postgresql supports this kind of things, it will be more conveniet for us.

Answer (score 2):

Once you rename a column, it's...gone.  You can't really get it back.

What you may be looking for is standard practice on how to migrate database changes and columns across.  The approach is less fancy, but works reliably:

- Create the new column you want to use
- Deploy code to utilize your new column
- Backfill data to your new column from your old column
- After the release, deprecate the old column by renaming it to something else
- In a new release, you can then fully remove the old column.

Comment: Is there a concept like a proxy column, where a column just uses the data of another column?

Comment: @Tanin:  No, I've not worked with or heard of anything like that before, but the concept of a "proxy column" is analogous to what I laid out above, just with more manual intervention.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. And, yes, the manual intervention is what I like to avoid.